# Add Today Button in datetimepicker with the below code

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I would like to add Today button in datetimepicker calender. I have an idea to add with the syntax **"todayBtn:true"**. But i dont know how to implement it while showing with the below code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input class="form-control date"  data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd  hh:ii"    data-link-field="dtp_input1" placeholder="select to validity" name="from_validity" type="text" id="shankar" value="">
    </body>
</html>
<script>
   $("#shankar").click(function () {
       $("#shankar").datetimepicker('show').on('changeDate',function(ev) {               
           $('.datetimepicker').hide();
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you specify which datetimepicker component are you using?

Comment: bootstrap datetimepicker

Comment: Which one? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 7):

Set following properties for your datepicker (todayBtn:"linked").

```
$('#dateFieldId').datepicker({
   todayBtn: "linked",
   todayHighlight : true,
   orientation: "left",
   autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: todayBtn: "linked" - thats the thing !

Answer (score 0):

Try `showButtonPanel: true`

```
$(function() {
    $( "#shankar" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfxdgeL1/1/)

Comment: No that's not working. And also i would like to change with the same code only as like in the show syntax

Comment: It is working, see jsfiddle in my answer, and there is no need to hide datepicker explicitly, hiding of the datepicker is done by the internal jquery code after you select the date.

Comment: When i click on Today, It's not working . i tried your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Today button takes you to today's date in calendar. For example: Go back one month, and click today then calendar will change to current month and today's date will be highlighted. This is the default behavior of jquery datepicker, you have to click on date in order to display it in input box.

Answer (score 0):

Include `jquery-ui` javascript and css and add the code
refer : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar

```
$(function() {
    $( "#shankar" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

And to put Todays date in the panel:

```
$('button.ui-datepicker-current').live('click', function() {
        $.datepicker._curInst.input.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide');
    });
```

Refer here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-datepicker-today-button

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) datetimepicker it would be as simple as that:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="shankar" class="form-control" name="from_validity" placeholder="select to validity">
     </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#shankar").datetimepicker({
            showTodayButton: true,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
        });
    });
 </script>
```